# GARCH model diagnostics: how to interpret test results?

Tags: garch, diagnostic

I'm new here and also new in Ox environment. Those below are results I obtained from estimating AR(5)-FIGARCH(1,$d$,1) models.

```
Normality Test
                   Statistic       t-Test      P-Value
Skewness           -0.028508      0.70640      0.47994
Excess Kurtosis       2.1108       26.159  7.8388e-151
Jarque-Bera           683.85         .NaN  3.1896e-149

Q-Statistics on Standardized Residuals**
--> P-values adjusted by 5 degree(s) of freedom 
Q( 10) =  41.5645   [0.0000001]**
Q( 15) =  51.7216   [0.0000001]**
Q( 20) =  58.0098   [0.0000006]**
Q( 25) =  65.8658   [0.0000008]**
Q( 30) =  67.4852   [0.0000090]**
H0 : No serial correlation ==> Accept H0 when prob. is High [Q < Chisq(lag)]

**Q-Statistics on Squared Standardized Residuals**
--> P-values adjusted by 2 degree(s) of freedom 
Q(  5) =  4.98843   [0.1726460]  
Q( 10) =  14.6018   [0.0673662]  
Q( 15) =  16.7924   [0.2089693]  
Q( 20) =  17.1298   [0.5142000]  
Q( 25) =  18.1990   [0.7466068]  
Q( 30) =  22.0400   [0.7794358]  
H0 : No serial correlation ==> Accept H0 when prob. is High [Q < Chisq(lag)]

**Diagnostic test based on the news impact curve (EGARCH vs. GARCH)**
                                     Test  P-value
Sign Bias t-Test                  1.55988  0.11879
Negative Size Bias t-Test         0.01090  0.99130
Positive Size Bias t-Test         2.38646  0.01701
Joint Test for the Three Effects  5.97232  0.11296

**ARCH-LM test**
ARCH 1-2 test:    F(2,3674) =  0.10906 [0.8967]  
ARCH 1-5 test:    F(5,3668) =  0.98214 [0.4270]  
ARCH 1-10 test:   F(10,3658)=   1.4771 [0.1412]  
ARCH 1-15 test:   F(15,3648)=   1.1139 [0.3371]  
ARCH 1-20 test:   F(20,3638)=  0.85385 [0.6478]  
ARCH 1-25 test:   F(25,3628)=  0.73108 [0.8299]  
ARCH 1-30 test:   F(30,3618)=  0.74544 [0.8398]

**Nyblom test**
Joint Statistic of the Nyblom test of stability: 14.2373
Individual Nyblom Statistics: 
Cst(M)           0.36252 #Constant in mean
AR(1)            3.48168
AR(2)            0.39023
AR(3)            0.41737
AR(4)            1.55922
AR(5)            1.23312
Cst(V)           0.52501 #Constant in variance
d-Figarch        4.12791
ARCH(Phi1)       4.29420
GARCH(Beta1)     4.55406
Asymmetry        1.30355
Tail             0.90821
Rem: Asymptotic 1% critical value for individual statistics = 0.75.
Asymptotic 5% critical value for individual statistics = 0.47.

**Adjusted Pearson Chi-square Goodness-of-fit test**
# Cells(g)  Statistic      P-Value(g-1)     P-Value(g-k-1)   
   40       40.4779         0.404929          0.046194
   50       46.9408         0.556995          0.126769
   60       57.9894         0.512788          0.130698
Rem.: k = 12 = # estimated parameters
```

**Questions:**

1. Why $t$-test of JB is `.NaN`?
2. How do I explain Box-Pierce test on residuals? For standardized residuals, it has no autocorrelation because residuals are filtered from AR(5). However, for squared standardized residuals, why are they still autocorrelated?
3. What does it mean if positive size effect is significant at 5% but sign effect is not significant?
4. ARCH effect here no longer exists, right?
5. Just 3 parameters have statistics below the critical value, so just 3 of them are constant over time. Does my model look good for forecasting?
6. I absolutely know nothing about the last test. Why are there 2 columns of $p$-values? Because I think $p$-value is too large so the model does fit the data, but one $p$-value is significant, i.e low, so how do I conclude about model?

Comment: For the last question 6. check out this powerpoint. It provides an idea on how to interpret it. https://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ589/univariateGarch2012powerpoint.pdf

Comment: @RNovice, for 6, the real issue seems to be presence of *two* columns of p-values. Otherwise, `rugarch` vignette covers the test, as indicated in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

A good source of information on diagnostic testing of univariate GARCH models is ["rugarch" vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rugarch/vignettes/Introduction_to_the_rugarch_package.pdf) by Alexios Ghalanos.

1. I can't tell why it is NaN, but the excess kurtosis is quite pronounced so that normality should be rejected. (JB test statistic is a weighted sum of squared skewness and squares excess kurtosis, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jarque%E2%80%93Bera_test).)
2. The table seems to be telling the opposite: standardized residuals are autocorrelated (the null of no autocorrelation can be rejected) while squared standardized residuals are not autocorrelated (the null cannot be rejected). If the test rejects for either levels or squares, it is not clear whether the conditional mean or the conditional variance model is at fault (because their effects interact from the perspective of the test); what is clear is that the current combination of cond. mean and cond. variance models is lacking.
3. ?
4. Yes, ARCH-LM test seems to be telling you that. However, ARCH-LM is not applicable on standardized residuals from a GARCH model; it is only applicable on raw data where no GARCH model has been fit yet. (But this is often ignored in software implementations.) The right test here would be Li-Mak test.
5. I think the parameters should ideally be constant, so Nyblom test results are quite disappointing. Hence, your model might not be very good for forecasting.
6. ? (But check the ["rugarch" vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rugarch/vignettes/Introduction_to_the_rugarch_package.pdf) for information about this test. There we find:

> The gof calculates the chi-squared goodness of fit test, which compares the empirical distribution of the standardized residuals with the theoretical ones from the chosen density. The
> implementation is based on the test of Palm (1996) which adjusts the tests in the presence on non-i.i.d. observations by reclassifying the standardized residuals not according to their value (as in the standard test), but instead on their magnitude, calculating the probability of observing a value smaller than the standardized residual, which should be identically standard uniform
> distributed.)

Comment: Thanks, Richard. You helped so much.
Are there any solutions to improve this model?

Comment: You could try playing with the lag orders of AR and GARCH. You could use an ARMA($p,q$) model for the conditional mean rather than a pure AR($p$) model as you have done now; ARMA is generally more parsimonious than AR. You could try a different flavour of the GARCH model (EGARCH or any other, there are so many of them).

Comment: I tried ARMA(3,3)-GARCH(1,1) but all AR terms had no significance, then I deleted all of them => become MA(3)-GARCH(1,1) but my R's results:
`Standardised Residuals Tests:
                                              p-Value          
 Ljung-Box Test(R)  Q(10)       0         
 Ljung-Box Test(R)  Q(15)       0         
 Ljung-Box Test(R)  Q(20)       0         
 Ljung-Box Test(R^2)  Q(10)   0.04150643
 Ljung-Box Test(R^2)  Q(15)   0.1132092 
 Ljung-Box Test(R^2)  Q(20)   0.2479505 
 LM Arch Test(R)                     0.04617054`
How I deal with Ljung-Box test? Did I reject ARCH effects?

Comment: I can't quite read the output you posted. Regarding ARCH effects, I have commented on them in my answer, try following by analogy.